# How to fix 'Sequence contains no matching elements' when dealing with json data type in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, json.net, fluent-migrator

I am using ASP.NET C# project using EF and backend as Postgresql DB. For mapping, Fluent Migrator is used. All works fine if I use primitive data types. But problem comes when I try to fetch or update data from DB having json columns.

My table has json column type (say, Payload as column name). I want to insert and get the Payload details. I am always getting the below error from EF.

> system.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching
>   element'

Please find my column setup and mapping.

Model.cs

```
public string Payload { get; set; }
```

DBModel.cs

```
public class MyClass
    {
        [Column("Payload", TypeName = "json")]
        public string Payload { get; set; }
    }
```

My DB has Payload column with json data type. when I try to fetch data from Repository (DB), getting the below error.

[image]

I could not figure out, what else I need to do to fetch the json value from Db. Can someone help me out on this?

Update 1:

Repository class (DB class) to get the data from Postgresql,

```
public MyClass Get(Guid id) =>
            _dbContext.MyData.FirstOrDefault(myData => myData.Id.Equals(id));
```

At this point, the error is throwing as shown in screenshot.

IDbContext.cs

```
IDbSet<MyClass> MyData { get; set; }
```

Comment: How are you inserting and retrieving the data?

Comment: Can you share the code which throws the exception?

Comment: I have added the code in "Update 1". Does it help? Also, I cannot completely share the code as this is real time project work.